# How to get rid of the manual class template parameter specification

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is there any more generic way to write a `Finalizer` class than this?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Finalizer
{
public:
    Finalizer(const std::function<T>& f) : _f(f) {}

    ~Finalizer()
    {
        _f();
    }

private:
    std::function<T> _f;
};

int main()
{
    Finalizer<void()> finalizer([]() { std::cout << "str" << std::endl; });
}
```

I want to get rid of the manual class template parameter specification to be able to write code like this:

```
Finalizer finalizer([]() { std::cout << "str" << std::endl; });
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not writing directly `std::function<void()>` ? Or give a default template parameter `typename T= void()` ?

Comment: @Garf365 To be more generic. Some finalizer methods can actually be a separate functions that can return error codes but I want to use them in the `Finalizer` class anyway and just ignore their error codes in such situations

Comment: @FrozenHeart Using `std::function<void()>` will automatically ignore the result, no problem here.

Comment: You may want to look up Andrei Alexandrescu's "“Declarative Control Flow" lecture.

Comment: Write a `make_finalizer` function. Also your destructor should check if `f_` is valid before calling it. Oh. and you don't have to use `std::function` at all here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ type deduction is only available for function templates, not for class templates.
You need a `make_finalizer` function to perform template argument deduction.

Also you don't have to use `std::function` at all, no need to pay for the runtime cost, unless you actually want it to be type-erased.

```
template <typename F>
class Finalizer
{
public:
    Finalizer(const F & c) : f_(c) {}
    Finalizer(F && c) : f_(std::move(c)) {}
    Finalizer(const Finalizer &) = delete;
    Finalizer(Finalizer && other) : 
          valid_(other.valid),
          f_(std::move(other.f_))
    {
         other.valid_ = false;
    }

    Finalizer& operator=(const Finalizer &) = delete;
    Finalizer& operator=(Finalizer && other)
    {
         Finalizer tmp(std::move(other));
         swap(tmp);
         return *this;
    }

    ~Finalizer()
    {
        if ( valid_ )
           f_();
    }

    void swap(Finalizer & other) noexcept
    {
         using std::swap;
         swap(other.valid_, valid_);
         swap(other.f_, f_);
    }

private:
    bool valid_ = true;
    F f_;
};

template<class F>
Finalizer< std::remove_reference_t<F> > at_scope_exit(F && x)
{
    return Finalizer< std::remove_reference_t<F> >(std::forward<F>(x));
}
```

And use it with auto:

```
 auto x = at_scope_exit([]() { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; });
```

Comment: Why do I need `std::forward` call here?

Comment: @FrozenHeart because you might want to copy the lambda inside the `Finalizer` instead of moving it.